# Modify command line arguments in bash script itself

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

Can i change command line arguments (like $1,$2) in bash script itself?
I tried stuffs like this:

```
$1='a'  
read var
$1=$var
```

Comment: Specifically glenn jackman's answer (not the accepted answer) on that duplicate.

Comment: Hm... though actually that's a poor duplicate because the *actual* question isn't about modifying the positional parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set built-in lets you do this.

From [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set):

> The remaining arguments shall be assigned in order to the positional parameters.

From [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> The remaining N arguments are positional parameters and are assigned, in order, to $1, $2, … $N.